# help with perl regex rules

Tags: regex, perl

I would need some help with a regex issue in perl. I need to match non_letter characters "nucleated" around letter characters string (of size one).

That is to say... I have a string like

```
CDF((E)TR)FT
```

and I want to match ALL the following:

```
C, D, F((, ((E), )T, R), )F, T.
```

I was trying with something like

```
/([^A-Za-z]*[A-Za-z]{1}[^A-Za-z]*)/
```

but I'm obtaining:

```
C, D, F((, E), T, R), F, T.
```

Is like if once a non-letter characters has been matched it can NOT be matched again in another matching.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A little late on this. Somebody has probably proposed this already.

I would consume the capture in the assertion to the left (via backref) and not consume the capture in the assertion to the right. All the captures can be seen, but the last one is not consumed, so the next pass continues right after the last atomic letter was found.

Character class is simplified for clarity:
`/(?=([^A-Z]*))(\1[A-Z])(?=([^A-Z]*))/`

`(?=([^A-Z]*))` # ahead is optional non A-Z characters, captured in grp 1
`(\1[A-Z])` # capture grp 2, consume capture group 1, plus atomic letter
`(?=([^A-Z]*))` # ahead is optional non A-Z characters, captured in grp 3

Do globally, in a while loop, combined groups `$2$3` (in that order) are the answer.

Test:

```
$samp = 'CDF((E)TR)FT';

while ( $samp =~ /(?=([^A-Z]*))(\1[A-Z])(?=([^A-Z]*))/g )
{
   print "$2$3, ";
}
```

output:

`C, D, F((, ((E), )T, R), )F, T,`

Comment: This solution works like a fuse and it works even with some other string with which I was having problems with the above solutions. Thanks a lot. But... could you please me comment or explain me a bit more about your solution. In particular what does it mean the "\1" ? The central parenthesis stuff is the only to consume characters? I would like to learn apart from having the solution. Thanx again.

Comment: Much more compact solution than mine. +1 @sln

Comment: @greem69: Sure, capture groups within an assertion are not consumed (ie: does not advance the current physical search position) unless it is referenced (thats the `\1` capture group 1) OUTSIDE of the assertion. So `\1` was a match and is a back reference that physically advances the search position so it can find the atomic Letter that advances it one more position. The last assertion  captures but does not advance the physical position in this itteration of the loop. So, all groups are captured and can be displayed, but the current position on each pass is right after the atomic letter ......

Comment: @sln: Thank you so much! For the solution and for the explanation. Maybe I'm just a beginner but your solution it seems great to me and I've learned a lot from it.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are consuming your characters or non letter characters the first time you encounter them, therefore you can't match all that you want. A solution would be to use different regexes for different patterns and combine the results at the end so that you could have your desired result :

This will match all character starting with a non character followed by a single character but NOT followed by a non character

```
[^A-Z]+[A-Z](?![^A-Z])
```

This will match a character enclosed by non characters, containing overlapping results :

```
(?=([^A-Z]+[A-Z][^A-Z]+))
```

This will match a character followed by one or more non characters only if it is not preceded by a non character :

```
(?<![^A-Z])[A-Z][^A-Z]+
```

And this will match single characters which are not enclosed to non characters

```
(?<![^A-Z])[A-Z](?![^A-Z])
```

By combining the results you will have the **correct desired result**:

```
C,D,T, )T, )F, ((E), F((, R)
```

Also if you understand the small parts you could join this into one Regex :

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

use strict;

my $subject = "0C0CC(R)CC(L)C0";

while ($subject =~ m/(?=([^A-Z]+[A-Z][^A-Z]+))|(?=((?<![^A-Z])[A-Z][^A-Z]+))|(?=((?<![^A-Z])[A-Z](?![^A-Z])))|(?=([^A-Z]+[A-Z](?![^A-Z])))/g) {
# matched text = $1, $2, $3, $4
print $1, " " if defined $1;
print $2, " " if defined $2;
print $3, " " if defined $3;
print $4, " " if defined $4;
}
```

Output :

```
0C0 0C C( (R) )C C( (L) )C0
```

Comment: Thank you FailedDev, your solution seems to works in the proposed example, but I've still some problems in other cases. Can you tell me what does it means "(?<!" in your solution?

Comment: No problem. (?<! means negative lookbehind. In other words assuming that you have a match somewhere it will "look behind your match" to make sure that the regex followed by (?<!"regex") does NOT match. Could you please tell me where you have problems so we can solve this too?

Comment: sure! If I give it the string C0CC(R)CC(L)C0 I obtain: 0C )C (R) (L) C0 C( C(. I would expect: C0 0C C( (R) )C C( (L) )C0. I'm using the global tag "g", but it seem we're missing something.

Comment: Please take a look at my edited answer. It should now be working as intented. If you have more problems let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You're right, once a character has been consumed in a regex match, it can't be matched again. In regex flavors that fully support [lookaround assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), you could do it with the regex

```
(?<=(\P{L}*))\p{L}(?=(\P{L}*))
```

where the match result would be the letter, and `$1` and `$2` would contain the non-letters around it. Since they are only matched in the context of lookaround assertions, they are not consumed in the match and can therefore be matched multiple times. You then need to construct the match result as `$1 + $& + $2`. This approach would work in .NET, for example.

In most other flavors (including Perl) that have limited support for lookaround, you can take a mixed approach, which is necessary because lookbehind expressions don't allow for indefinite repetition:

```
\P{L}*\p{L}(?=(\P{L}*))
```

Now `$&` will contain the non-letter characters before the letter and the letter itself, and `$1` contains any non-letter characters that follow the letter.

```
while ($subject =~ m/\P{L}*\p{L}(?=(\P{L}*))/g) {
    # matched text = $& . $1
}
```

Comment: This does not seem to work under perl 5.12.4

    `#!/usr/local/bin/perl  
    use strict;  
    my $subject = "CDF((E)TR)FT";  
    while ($subject =~ m/\P{L}*\p{L}(?=(\P{L}*))/g) {  
    # matched text = $& . $1  
    print $& . $1, "\n";  
}`  

No output at all.

Comment: Could it be that that version of Perl doesn't have full Unicode support?

Comment: No because this : `while ($subject =~ m/\p{L}/g) {
 # matched text = $&
}` Prints all the letters just fine.

Comment: Hm, strange. I don't know Perl, so I have no idea what could be going wrong here. The regex tests fine in RegexBuddy (and that's a generated code snippet from RegexBuddy)...

Comment: Thank you so much Tim, but I have the problem that FailedDev described here above. No output at all.

Comment: Anyway thank you for your help and for the lookaround assertion address! I'm learning something more.

Comment: For some strange reason in this form (\P{L}) works: `(?=(\P{L}*))(\1\p{L})(?=(\P{L}*))`, but only (\p{L}) works in form explicit negative class: `[^\p{L}]*\p{L}(?=([^\p{L}]*))`. I think it is a bug in Perl, which is troubling.

Answer (score 1):

Or, you could do it the hard way and tokenize first, then process the tokens:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $str = 'CDF((E)TR)FT';
my @nucleated = nucleat($str);
print "$_\n" for @nucleated;

sub nucleat {
    my($s) = @_;
    my @parts;   # return list stored here

    my @tokens = grep length, split /([a-z])/i, $s;

    # bracket the tokens with empty strings to avoid warnings
    unshift @tokens, '';
    push @tokens, '';

    foreach my $i (0..$#tokens) {
        next unless $tokens[$i] =~ /^[a-z]$/i; # one element per letter token       
        my $str = '';

        if ($tokens[$i-1] !~ /^[a-z]$/i) { # punc before letter
            $str .= $tokens[$i-1];
        }

        $str .= $tokens[$i];               # the letter

        if ($tokens[$i+1] !~ /^[a-z]$/i) { # punc after letter
            $str .= $tokens[$i+1];
        }

        push @parts, $str;
    }

    return @parts;
}
```

Comment: Ei tadmc, thank you so much for your help. The problem is that I want to do it with regex, because after this basic issue I'll need to "nucleate" around more and more complex forms than simply one letter characters. And for that I need regex. But thank you anyway!

Comment: You can easily adapt what I posted to "more complex forms" than a single letter.